# Programming with split screens ?! Plugins?

Tags: split, screen

Hi :) im looking for an IDE (VIM, visual studio, whatever) which can do the following :

lets say ive got some code and i see a method,

now i want the screen to split and show the methodcode next to the code i read before, so i dont lose the line.

if i choose another codeline on the left side, i want the right side to respond to it,

so left side shud be for overview and right side for zooming in :)

does anyone know a plugin or anything for this ?

thanks for all the help :)

Answer (score 0):

I think ack.vim (https://github.com/mileszs/ack.vim/) would be worth a look. 
It is no automatically switching to the code, when you select a new function, but otherwise is should fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

its a pitty that there is nothing out there that works like I described. but thanks !! :)

Anyway, i found a compromise just to let you know.

i feel like "call hierachy" is the right term to look for.
Most ides have it and its kinda like a structure overview thing :)

if ur on visual studio also try ALT + F12 // it will show u the method definition within the code ur atm.

good luck and happy programming everybody :)